# jQuery Link Navigation Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I've been trying to get this too work for a while.

Basically we've just rebuilt the mobile/desktop version of our site. Now we are now trying to create a quick jQuery script to make pages and links that contain our URL to load using the .load() jQuery feature. We don't want to go back over the 97 pages, and 10 scripts. This is what we are currently using...

```
<a href=<?php echo PROTOCOL."secure3.idsma.".URL."/secure/user/authentication/sso/login/initiate?returnURL=$return"; ?>">
```

and this is what we are trying to get the script to do.

```
<a onclick="$('html').load('<?php echo PROTOCOL."secure3.idsma.".URL."/secure/user/authentication/sso/login/initiate?returnURL=$return"; ?>')">
```

But I'm trying to make it  more effiecent by making a script that can detect the link is from our site and add a class that triggers a jQuery function to load the pages.

Also when the link is clicked how would i get the .scrollToTop() jQuery function to work?

Thanks for any help. Sorry my English sentence structure isn't great.

Please help if you can. Thanks in advanced again for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd think you'd have to do something like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   // find all the links within the document
   $('a').click(function(ev){
      // handle the click on internal link here, recognized by existence of secure3.idsma string
      if($(this).attr('href').indexOf('secure3.idsma') !== -1)
      {
          ev.preventDefault();

          // load the link via ajax
          $.ajax({
              url: $(this).attr('href'),
              success: function(response){
                   // populate the html, and use animate to scroll to the top
                   $("html").html(response).add('body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 });
              }
          });
      }
   });
});
```

However, I'd advise against using AJAX this way - generally, you don't want to reload the entire document; you want to reload the parts of document that are actually changing, so, probably some `div#main-container`, etc. Also bear in mind that you'll have to apply this function on the content that you've inserted (so probably this script should be in some bootstrap)

Comment: If I was to also implement this on the main site as well as the authentication site how would i get it to detect the URL?

Comment: You'd have to change the `secure3.idsma`. Actually, you can make JS take care of this for you by using `window.location.host` - so `$(this).attr('href').indexOf(window.location.host) !== -1` and now this will target all the links that are on the same domain/subdomain.

Comment: @blex when ive implemented I get a security warning and it doesn't load the pages in because of it. Google Chrome Windows!

Comment: Bear in mind that for this to work, the protocol, domain and port for ajax requests must match the window from which the event propagated (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). You can change the condition to be `$(this).attr('href').indexOf(window.location.protocol+"//"+window.location.host)` which should now target links that fulfill that condition (we're not really bothered about ports here, as you rarely use different ports for specific links)

Comment: If I give you the link to the site could you join and message me that way?

Comment: Sure - I'll try, time permitting :)

Answer (score 0):

You could listen for clicks on your links, and check if the link is from your website. If it is, then load the data dynamically and `return false` to prevent the link from reloading the page.

```
$(document).on('click','a', function(e){
    var isFromMySite = e.currentTarget.href.indexOf('secure3.idsma.') > -1;

    if(isFromMySite){
        $('html').load(this.href);
        return false;
    }
});
```

#### JS Fiddle demo